# Tangent line of a vector valued function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find parametric equations of the tangent line to the circular helix
>   $$x=\cos \color{red}{t},\quad y=\sin \color{red}{t},\quad z=\color{red}{t}$$ Where $\color{red}{t}=\color{red}{t_0}$, and use that result to ﬁnd parametric equations for the tangent line at the point
>   where $\color{red}{t}=\color{red}{\pi}$.

**Solution**:

> The vector equation of the tangent line at $\color{red}{t}=\color{red}{t_0}$ is
>   \begin{align}
> \textbf{r}=&\cos \color{red}{t_0}\vec{i}+\sin \color{red}{t_0}\vec{j}+\color{red}{t_0}\vec{k}+\color{green}{t}[-\sin \color{red}{t_0}\vec{i}+\cos \color{red}{t_0}\vec{j}+\vec{k}] \quad \text{Using }\textbf{r}=\vec{r}(t_0)+t\vec{r'}(t_0)\\
> &=(\cos \color{red}{t_0}-\color{green}{t}\sin \color{red}{t_0})\vec{i}+(\sin \color{red}{t_0}+\color{green}{t}\cos \color{red}{t_0})\vec{j}+(\color{red}{t_0}+\color{green}{t})\vec{k}
> \end{align}
>   Thus, the parametric equations of the tangent line at $\color{red}{t}=\color{red}{\pi}$ are$$x=-1,\quad y=-\color{green}{t}, \quad z=\pi+\color{green}{t}$$

**My question**:
A parametrization of the line through a point $r(t_0)$ and parallel to the vector $\vec{r'}(t_0)$ is the parametrization of the tangent line at $t_0$ $$\textbf{r}=\vec{r}(t_0)+t\vec{r'}(t_0)$$ Isn't we want 
the line $\textbf{r}$ to pass through $\vec{r}(t_0)$ When $t=t_0$ then it should be $$\textbf{r}=\vec{r}(t_0)+(t-t_0)\vec{r'}(t_0)\qquad -(1)$$ But using $(1)$ I get different answer. Actually My confusion began with these following paragraph which I found at [mathinsight](https://mathinsight.org/parametrized_curve_tangent_line)

> A parametrization of the line through a point a and parallel to the vector $v$ is $l(t)=a+tv$. Setting $a=c(t_0)$ and $v=c′(t_0)$, we obtain a parametrization of the tangent line: $$l(t)=c(t_0)+tc′(t_0)\quad (2)$$
>   However, we typically want the line given by $l(t)$
>   to pass through $c(t_0)$ when $t=t_0$. So we usually change the parametrization slightly to
>   $$l(t)=c(t_0)+(t−t_0)c′(t_0)\quad (3)$$

**Maybe explaining the difference between $(2)$ and $(3)$ clear my whole confusion**.

Comment: The quoted solution and yours use $t$ to mean two different things. In particular, you shouldn’t use the same variable as the parameter of the curve _and_ of the tangent line to it. In particular, you mix the two uses in the term $t\overrightarrow{r_0'}(t)$.

Comment: agreed let me edit it @amd Sir

Comment: That’s precisely the error that you’re making.

Comment: Can you take a look now @amd Sir

Comment: You’re still confusing the $t$ that is the parameter of the curve with the $t$ that is the parameter of the line. Use an entirely different symbol for the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $(2)\implies\mathbf{r_1}=⟨-1,-t,\pi+t⟩$ and $(3)\implies\mathbf{r_2}=⟨-1,\pi-t,t⟩$ 
>   $(2)\implies\mathbf{r_1(\pi)}=⟨-1,-\pi,2\pi⟩$ and $(3)\implies\mathbf{r_2(\pi)}=⟨-1,0,\pi⟩$

and let your parametric equations of circular helix is $\mathbf c(t)=⟨\cos t,\sin t,t⟩$. Which give you $\mathbf c(\pi)=⟨-1,0,\pi⟩$
Now from here maybe your confusion start why $\mathbf{r_1(\pi)}$ isn't same as $\mathbf c(\pi)$. Please note that $\mathbf{r_1(t)}$ and $\mathbf{r_2(t)}$ are the different parametrization of same tangent line. To make it convenient [mathinsight](https://mathinsight.org/parametrized_curve_tangent_line) change the parameter slightly to make sure $\mathbf{r_2(t)}$ match $\mathbf {c(t)}$ at every point $t$ as mentioned. By the way you can see that $\mathbf{r_1(0)}=\mathbf {c(\pi)}$.
Am I correctly caught you$?$

Comment: Yes. @amd answer is more informative but you caught me exactly where I got confused Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question illustrates why it’s generally not a good idea to use the same symbol for two different things. Unfortunately, that quoted section from mathinsight makes the same error and then only adds to the confusion in that part about “we typically want the line ... to pass through $c(t_0)$ when $t=t_0$.”. The value $t_0$ of the parameter of the curve at which we’re computing the tangent line has nothing to do with the values of the parameter for points on the tangent line itself. Indeed, I’d go so far as to say that wanting $l(t_0)=c(t_0)$ is rather *atypical*.  You make the same error in your solution, which I believe is the source of your confusion. Now, if you were examining the two curves in isolation, reusing the parameter name would present no difficulties. However, the two curves interact at the point $\mathbf r(t_0)$, so it’s better to use different names for the two parameters in order to keep things straight.

In this exercise, you’re given a curve described by the vector function $\mathbf r:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3$ with a parameter called $t$. If we fix $t$ to be some value, call it $t_0$, then the tangent line at $\mathbf r(t_0)$ can be indeed be parameterized as $\mathbf r(t_0)+t\mathbf r'(t_0)$, as you’ve written. Note, however, that the $t$ in this latter expression is **not** the same as the $t$ in the expression for $\mathbf r$. They are two different parameters for two different curves that have almost nothing to do with each other, so instead of reusing the name $t$, let’s instead use $s$ for the parameterization of the line, i.e., write it as $\mathbf r(t_0)+s\mathbf r'(t_0)$. Once you’ve done that, there should be no question about what’s going on: this line obviously passes through $\mathbf r(t_0)$ when $t=t_0$ (as given) and $s=0$.